# FieldValue.arrayRemove() to remove all objects from an array in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a flutter app and there is a User model which contains name,email,uid and cart. I have created a CartController extends GetxController  to add items to cart and remove a particular item from cart. However, I need to create a function which deletes all the items from the cart which contains cart item as objects. I know that a particular cart item can be removed using FieldValue.arrayRemove() but I want to know how can i delete all the elements from the array.

Comment: Maybe just set value of that array to an empty array `[]`?

Comment: I'm looking for the dart syntax . @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially trying to set `cart` array to an empty array. You can just use `update` method as in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#dart_8):

```
final docRef = db.collection("collection").doc("docId");

docRef.update({"cart": []}).then(
    (value) => print("DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!"),
    onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"));
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch ;)

Comment: Wasn't my question, but I did upvote!

Comment: @Petro ah my bad. I didn't saw the name 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .clear() on the array variable.

Try

```
FieldValue.clear()
```